# How to resolve runtime error caused for stl_iterator due to reference binding to null pointer of type int?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list, stdvector

I have been trying to solve this problem on Leetcode about deep copying a Linked list with an additional random pointer to each node.

for the same, I have thought of doing this in a two step process i.e. first create a deep copy of the linked list just with the next nodes and then later construct the random pointer assignment.

To construct the random pointer assignment, I am

1. creating a vector with value from random pointer of each node
2. Then writing a constructRandom function which takes the  head and the above obtained vector as input and iterates through the linked list to find the node with value equal to the first value of the vector and then removing the first value from the vector.
3. recursively calling the same function until all the nodes are done

I know this is very inefficient way as it appears to me of complexity O(n!). But while implementing this I came across certain error, which I want to figure out before I think of another efficient solution. The error is

```
Line 789: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_iterator.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:16
```

Here is my complete code of the class LinkedList,

```js
class Solution {
public:
    Node* constructDeepCopy(Node* head){
        if(!head){
            return head;
        }
        Node* newNode = new Node(head->val);
        newNode->next = constructDeepCopy(head->next);
        return newNode;
    }
    Node* constructRandom(Node* head, vector<int> values){
        Node* curr = head, *temp=head;
        if(head == NULL){
            return NULL;
        }
        while (temp){
            if(values.front() == temp->val){
                curr->random = temp;
                values.erase(values.begin());
                break;
            }
            else if(values.front() == 10001){
                curr->random = NULL;
                values.erase(values.begin());
                break;
            }
            else{
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        if(values.size()>0){
        curr->next->random = constructRandom(curr->next, values);
        }
        return curr;
        
    }
    Node* copyRandomList(Node* head) {
        vector<int> value{};
        Node* newNode = constructDeepCopy(head);
        Node* curr = head->random;
        while(curr){
            if(curr == NULL){
                value.push_back(10001);
            }
            else{
                value.push_back(curr->val);
            }
            curr = curr->random;
        }
        newNode = constructRandom(newNode, value);
        return newNode;
        
    }
};
```

can anyone please help me point out the error. I believe this error must be similar to that of out of bounds exception that arises with arrays but I can not find out where I am going out of bounds here.

Thank you.

Comment: Your specific issue aside, that `new` without a single `delete` in sight is enough by itself to know something very wrong is happening here.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I should be deleting the temp but for other new with new Node, I was asked to perform a deep copy and hence I kept creating a new Node for every Node in the original Linked list.

Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Also I have to mention, I made a bad choice in naming a variable as newNode which has nothing to do with the heap memory allocation.

Comment: as you seem to use c++11, you shoud use unique_ptr, compile time errors would even help you to code it correctly